# php mysql update with two tables not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing an update using two tables but for some reason it is not working and not generating an error, so I cannot find the problem. Can someone please shed some light onto this? Why is this not working?

```
$upd = "
UPDATE table t
     , images i 
   SET t.image_blob = i.image_blob 
 WHERE t.record_id='".$rid."' 
   AND i.image_id='".$iid."'";<br>
$dbh->exec($upd);
```

In other words, I want to take a specific record from the images table (where the `image_id=$iid`) and update table (t) where the `record_id=$rid`.

Comment: You have a `<br>` after the command. Did you miss that?

Comment: You don't need keyword `table`, just `UPDATE t, images i...`

Comment: Is your table really called `table`? That's a reserved word and can't be used as an identifier without quoting it with backticks. But it would be better to just rename it if you can. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Try to use join..

Answer (score 0):

In your code, first you says you are goint to update 2 tables, but then you only update the table t.
If the tables are not relationed with foreing keys, you can try the next:

```
$upd = "
UPDATE table t
   SET t.image_blob = (SELECT i.image_blob FROM images i WHERE i.image_id='".$iid."') 
 WHERE t.record_id='".$rid."'";
$dbh->exec($upd);
```

else, you can try the solution given at [Update a single table based on data from multiple tables SQL Server 2005,2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596552/update-a-single-table-based-on-data-from-multiple-tables-sql-server-2005-2008) using "FROM" and "JOIN's"